# KnockoutJS Associative Array and Select Lists

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I currently have a number box in which the user can enter a number 1, 2, or 3, and based on that, there is some conditional formatting.

However, I want the number field to instead be a dropdown list which displays something like "Short", "Long", and "Very Long", but behind the scenes, the real values being passed around are 0, 1, or 2. Getting it to work with only numbers being displayed is easy, however, I am having a hard time figuring out how to pair 0 with "Short", and so on.

Here is a fiddle with how far I was able to get before things started breaking: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxh8e9qv/7/. As a side note, I also can't seem to get the current length values to populate the dropdown, either.

The important areas in the code are:

**HTML**

```
<select  data-bind='options: lengthTypes, value: length' />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Furniture = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable('');
   self.size = ko.observable('');
   self.length = ko.observable();
   self.lengthTypes = ko.observableArray([0,1,2]);
```

Once again, what I am trying to do is have a dropdown list with human readable options, but in the back end be passing around index numbers (0,1,2). Many thanks.

I am aware of the official KnockoutJS [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), but their solution seems to be creating objects to fill the `lengthTypes` array, which seems too heavy weight for what I want.

Comment: Look at example 3. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Yep. That does what I want, but as I commented on the answer, I didn't want to declare a bunch of new objects. It wasn't clean enough. Using JSON worked well and was cleaner than the solution on that page.

Comment: Not sure you mean by JSON objects. I don't see any JSON. Do you mean object literals?

Comment: Perhaps so. Can you tell I'm a newb? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ***optionsText*** and ***optionsValue*** bindings, but you'll need to change lengthTypes to an observableArray with objects at each index.

For example - [JSFiddle if you're interested](http://jsfiddle.net/ntck5fyg/)

**HTML**

```
<select  data-bind="options: lengthTypes,optionsText:'label',optionsValue:'value', value: length" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Furniture = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable('');
   self.size = ko.observable('');
   self.length = ko.observable();
   self.lengthTypes = ko.observableArray([{label: 'Short', value: 0 },{label: 'Long', value: 1 },{label: 'Very Long', value: 2 }]);
}
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Loving the usage of JSON objects within the `lengthTypes` array. I don't know how I didn't think of that before! It definitely looks a lot more lightweight than Knockout's official examples.

Comment: Thanks again. For any future readers, do note that the quotations around the `optionsText` and `optionsValue` are mandatory, whereas it is not needed for the value option.